# RouterView KeepAlive not working with nested component inside layout

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

My problem is simple, but I can't figure out how to fix it, no matter what I do. I'm using Vue3 with [VueRouter](https://router.vuejs.org/)

This is my `App` component.

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { RouterView } from 'vue-router'
import { onErrorCaptured } from "vue";
import useStateStore from './stores/state';

export default {
  components: {
    RouterView,
  },
  setup() {
    onErrorCaptured((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  },
  watch: {
    '$i18n.locale': function (newVal, oldVal) {
      useStateStore().setLanguage(newVal)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <RouterView :key="$route.fullPath" v-slot="{ Component }">
    <KeepAlive>
    <template v-if="Component">
      <Suspense timeout=0>
        <!-- main content -->
        <template #default>
          <component :is="$route.meta.layout || 'div'">
            <component :is="Component" />
          </component>
        </template>
        <!-- loading state -->
        <template #fallback>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
            <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
              <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>
      </Suspense>
    </template>
  </KeepAlive>
  </RouterView>
</template>
```

**EDIT**
Even this simple example is not working

```js
<template>
  <RouterView :key="$route.fullPath" v-slot="{ Component }">
    <KeepAlive>
          <component :is="$route.meta.layout || 'div'">
            <component :is="Component" />
          </component>
  </KeepAlive>
  </RouterView>
</template>
```

No matter what I do, nothing inside `KeepAlive` is being cached. I don't components inside `KeepAlive` to reload (running `mounted, created` functions etc.)

I've tried;

1. Using the `:key` on `RouterView` component
2. Trying to place `KeepAlive` in different places inside component
3. Trying to use `:included` with `KeepAlive`
4. Validate that `$route.fullPath` is actually a path to a view

Comment: The question doesn't explain what you do to test this and how exactly you expect it to work.

Comment: @EstusFlask updated, tnx

Comment: There's still no clear explanation. What do you do for keep-alive to NOT work? Do you navigate different routes? In this case it will surely reload because the whole RouterView hierarchy is re-mounted. If the intention is to not re-mount the layout, probably you don't need it to make a child of routerview in the first place